# PAR packer is not including user defined modules

Tags: perl-module, pp-perl-par-packager

I have a Perl script test.pl which includes another Perl module fact.pm which is under crypt/Module dir.
the source code of crypt/test.pl is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);
use File::Path;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use File::Basename qw(dirname);
use Cwd  qw(abs_path);
use lib dirname(dirname abs_path $0);
use crypt::Module::fact qw(factorial);

&factorial();#function present in fact.pm
print("Thanks for that thought \n");
```

The PAR packer command given is

```
pp -M Module::fact -o test test.pl
```

on copying just the executable test on a different directory path and executing it I am getting the below error:

```
Can't locate crypt/Module/fact.pm in @INC (you may need to install the crypt::Module::fact module)
```

how is it possible to include the module in the executable?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend using the -c and/or -x options for the [pp](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) utility, which are used "to determine additonal run-time dependencies".  I've gotten into the habit of using both.

Although you are using the -M option to add a module, I think that you have a typo with that option.  In your code, you are using a "crypt::Module::fact" module, but you are specifying a "Module::fact" module with the -M option.  Perhaps if you used "-M crypt::Module::fact" instead of "-M Module::fact", your problem may be solved.

Also, you might need to use -I (or -lib) to specify the path to any additional module library directories.